# gitlab (puma, sidekiq) how minimalize memory use

Tags: memory, gitlab, sidekiq, ram, puma

I have gitlab on my VPS with 4GB ram. But after upgrade debion to version 10 and upgrade gitlab, momory is not enough. Puma and Sidekiq occupied cca 13% of memory.
I reduce some parametrs in gitlab.rb, but it help only little.

Have somebody advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

2.5gb of physical RAM + 1gb of `swap` should be enough to currently run Gitlab in 2022:

- [Running Gitlab in a memory constrained environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/memory_constrained_envs.html)